# vba: delete filtered rows but not first one (or store it and paste after deletion)

Tags: vba, excel, runtime-error, autofilter

Working on Microsoft Visual Basic Application Edition 7.1 in Excel 2013
Data are on columns from A to D, rows' number varies from time to time. I would like to delete all rows for which column B's value doesn't start with LCR (and also I would like not to bore with a for...next loop).
Something like:

```
Columns("B:B").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>LCR*"
Selection.Delete
```

Unfortunately, this code deletes heading row (row number 1) and I don't want.
I tried to store row number 1 elsewhere in a range variable, but it doesn't work (run-time error '424')

```
Set r1 = Range("A1:D1")
r1.Copy
Columns("B:B").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>LCR*"
Selection.Delete
With Range("A1:D1")
    .Insert Shift:=xlDown
    .Select
    .Value = r1.Value
End With
```

How can I tell the filter to start from row number two (or how can I correctly store content of row number one so to paste it after deletion by filter)?
Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define your range for deleting as `Range(Cells(2,2),Cells(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count,2))`  (To replace the `Selection` call).  This will delete everything except for the first cell in the column

Edit to avoid excel prompt: `Range(Cells(2,2),Cells(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count,2)).EntireRow`

Comment: It first prompts "Delete entire row?", and then after my "Ok" it works. Do you know any built-in Ok or "please don't bother"? I mean, anything different from Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Comment: @user3664452 perhaps if you have it select the entire range, so `Range(Cells(2,2),Cells(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.count,2).EntireRow)`.   Admittedly, I've never encountered an issue with vba prompting about a deletion.  I think the EntireRow call should clear that up though (I always use it out of habit when deleting so that looking back on my code it is clear to me what was deleted)

Comment: If that doesn't work, I believe the only other method is the DisplayAlerts = False.  Is there a reason you don't want to use that method in your code?  You can always enclose the command (ie False before then return to True after deletion) if you don't want it to affect other parts of the code

Comment: the entirerow solution works and doesn't prompt  Range(Cells(2, 2), Cells(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count, 2)).EntireRow.Delete

Comment: @user3664452  Glad to hear it :)  If you wouldn't mind, mark my answer as accepted to move this out of the unanswered question queue

Answer (score 0):

in a more complete way you could go like this

```
Sub main()

    With Worksheets("MyWantedSheet") '<--| always specify full worksheet reference (change "MyWantedSheet" with your actual sheet name)
        With .Columns("B:B") '.Resize(.Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row) '<--| refer to wanted column range down to its last non empty cell
            .AutoFilter '<--| remove possible preeeding autofilter filtering
            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>LCR*" '<--| apply current filtering
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Cells) > 1 Then '<--| if there are visible cells other than the "header" one
                .Resize(.Parent.Cells(.Parent.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row - 1).Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete '<--|delete visible rows other than the first ("headers") one
            End If
        End With
        .AutoFilterMode = False '<--| remove drop-down arrows
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Yes. The difference is the handling of all possible data "structure" i.e. its "absolute" position in the worksheet and its "relative" one with respect of other data in the same worksheet.